# how to use includes() after shift() of array of objects

Tags: javascript

1 - I have an interval going that loops through an array of players.

2 - the array is an array of objects. 
example of object

```
 {
                        id      : "100",
                        fname   : "tom",
                        lname   : "smith",
                        position: 15,
                        team    : "Giants"
                    };
```

3 - the array has many players so for example 
players_list = `[ {"id":"2218","avg":"60.9189","min":"1","max":"380","fname":"Patrick","lname":"Mahomes","position":"QB","team":"Chiefs"},{"id":"65","avg":"48.6216","min":"1","max":"194","fname":"Josh","lname":"Allen","position":"QB","team":"Bills"},{"id":"416","avg":"58.3784","min":"1","max":"213","fname":"Drew","lname":"Brees","position":"QB","team":"Saints"},{"id":"591","avg":"69.0270","min":"1","max":"231","fname":"Derek","lname":"Carr","position":"QB","team":"Raiders"},{"id":"840","avg":"61.1081","min":"1","max":"252","fname":"Sam","lname":"Darnold","position":"QB","team":"Jets"}]`

4 - during each loop I take the first using players_list.shift();

5 - then I store each selected player in another array of objects of same structure called selected_players_list. which would include each player that has been selected from shift.

6 - the issue is that the above is only 1 of the ways a player can be selected another way is manually by the user which will also be added into selected_players_list.

7 - I want to automatically remove any player that has been manually selected from being picked again by removing the player from the players_list

8 - I have this code.

```
// loop through the players array
     players_list.forEach(function(element) {
// check if the object exists in the other array 
                            if(selected_players_list.includes(element)){
                                console.log('FOUND');
                                debugger;
// get the index of that object found
    let found = total_result_player_data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === element.id);
                                if(found !== -1){
                                    console.log('SPLICED -> ' + found);
// remove it from players list array
                                    players_list.splice(found, 1);
                                    console.log(players_list);
                                //    debugger;
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

9 - after that I want to shift the first player from the array.

```
object_random_pick = players_list.shift();
```

10 - but on second loop the includes does not find that player in the selected_players_list array anymore.

11 - it works correctly if I use this instead.

```
object_random_pick = players_list[0];
```

12 - however then its using the same pick repeatedly which isn't what I want. 
I don't want any player used more then once.

Comment: If you remove elements from the array you are iterating you will get unexpected behavior. For example, const a = [1,2]; a.forEach(e => { a.shift(); console.log(e); }); you will only print 1 you never will iterate to element 2 due to the array length is modified. Don't mutate what you are iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `.splice` or `.shift` inside of loop. You change array before loop finish this work. If you want give remove some element from array you must use `.filter`

This code just example how you can use `.filter`

````
players_list = [ {"id":"2218","avg":"60.9189","min":"1","max":"380","fname":"Patrick","lname":"Mahomes","position":"QB","team":"Chiefs"},{"id":"65","avg":"48.6216","min":"1","max":"194","fname":"Josh","lname":"Allen","position":"QB","team":"Bills"},{"id":"416","avg":"58.3784","min":"1","max":"213","fname":"Drew","lname":"Brees","position":"QB","team":"Saints"},{"id":"591","avg":"69.0270","min":"1","max":"231","fname":"Derek","lname":"Carr","position":"QB","team":"Raiders"},{"id":"840","avg":"61.1081","min":"1","max":"252","fname":"Sam","lname":"Darnold","position":"QB","team":"Jets"}]

// loop through the players array
const chekedPlayers = players_list.filter(function(element) {
    // check if the object exists in the other array 
    if (selected_players_list.includes(element)) {
        console.log('FOUND');
        //debugger;
        // get the index of that object found
        let found = total_result_player_data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === element.id);
        if (found !== -1) {
            console.log('SPLICED -> ' + found);
            // remove it from players list array
            return false; //
            console.log(players_list);
            //    debugger;
        }

        return true;
    }
});```

You can read doc of `.filter` and use how you need.
````

Comment: should this only be used outside the loop? or can I use it inside the loop without the const and use var instead? how can I pull only the first value if I don't use shift or does that also need to be outside the loop? thanks for any help.

Comment: Please give me full example of code, and type inside  comment with your question, it's a little hard  give answer without details